# updating firebase using expo client

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am working on a react native app, I use firebase, I recently updated expo, and when I use this command `expo start`, everything works but I get this message on the logs:

```
Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently installed expo package version:
 - firebase - expected version range: 7.9.0 - actual version installed: ^8.2.0 Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages. To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...] Starting Metro Bundler
```

when use `expo install firebase` i get the following error:

```
Installing 1 SDK 37.0.0 compatible native module using Yarn.
 > yarn add firebase@7.9.0
'yarnpkg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 spawn yarnpkg ENOENT
Error: spawn yarnpkg ENOENT
```

how can I correctly update firebase?

Answer (score 0):

first do
npm install yarn -g

after that is complete
then do

yarn add firebase@7.9.0

Comment: thank you it didnt work though I stll get  that
 'firebase - expected version range: 7.9.0 - actual version installed: ^8.2.0'

Comment: Another thing you can try is, 
Delete node_modules, any lock files (package.lock or yarn.lock). Then in package.json under dependencies, change the version of firebase to 7.9.0. Then do a yarn install or npm install